# How can i sort the results by date and time between 2 users (Chat/Messages)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

How to sort the results of messages between two users by date and time according to who wrote first `from=15 to=13`

sql rows

```
1 15 13 message1 10/08/2018 10:06:54am
2 13 15 message2 10/08/2018 10:08:34am
3 13 15 message3 10/08/2018 10:28:34am
```

ids

```
$user_id = 13
$company_id = 15
```

query

```
$query= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Messages')
            ->FindBy(array('too' => $user_id,'fromm'=>$company_id ));
```

ids

```
$user_id = 13
$company_id = 15
```

query1

```
    $query1 = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Messages')
                ->FindBy(array('fromm' => $user_id,'too'=>$company_id ));
```

result

```
message2

10/08/2018 10:08:34am
message3

10/08/2018 10:28:34am
message1

10/08/2018 10:06:54am
```

Comment: from 15 to 13 what?

Comment: from=user_id too=user_id

Comment: I might not get the question, but that data already is sorted?! What exactly is it you want?

Comment: Your sample already appears to be in order - can you show what order you want it in.

Comment: What do you need so? A query to get all message from two user order by date and time? Some php to sort the result? If you need a query, we need your database structure for at least the table message and user

Answer (score 0):

Thinking slightly outside the obvious box, the order that these messages happened can be seen by looking at the `id`. You can forget about the Date and Time.

So all you need to do is add an `Order By id` to get the messages returned in the order they happened.

> If I understand your database rows, the Date and Time look like they were not stored in a DATETIME type column. That is going to make processing these rows far more difficult for you later.